# Circle shape in turtle with smaller radius

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

This is my first question on StackOverflow, so bear with me. I am trying to have my turtle's shape be a small circle. However, the default circle is too big for my project. Is there a way to make it smaller? My company won't let me load a gif file to be the shape of a turtle.

What I've tried so far is with a gif file where I do:

```
import turtle 

screen = turtle.Screen() 
screen.register_shape('circle1', 'circle.gif')
t = turtle.Turtle() 
t.shape('circle1') 
t.forward(10)
```

This works but uses a gif file, which my company doesn't allow. Is there a way I can do this without a gif?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is input the polynomial corresponding to the size of the circle you want.
`register_shape` takes in more than just a file name, it can also take in coordinates.

i.e. `screen.register_shape(name, coordinates)` is another way of using that function.

If you want to make the circle smaller, draw the circle with the corresponding size and append it to a list. Then convert that list into a tuple and that can be your new shape.

In general you can draw any shape, append the coordinates and use that.

Here is an example for a circle:

**Specific Example**

```
import turtle 

def drawCircle(radius,iterations, t): # returns tuples 
     coords = [] 
     for i in range(iterations): 
          t.forward(radius) 
          t.right(360.0/iterations) 
          coords.append((t.xcor(), t.ycor()))
     return tuple(coords)

t = turtle.Turtle()
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.register_shape('myCircle', drawCircle(1, 72, t))

t.shape('myCircle')
```

**General Example**

```
import turtle


def drawShape(t): 
   coords = [] 
   while # turtle move 
       coords.append((t.xcor(), t.ycor()))
   return tuple(coords) 

t = turtle.Turtle()
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.register_shape('myShape', drawShape(t))
t.shape('myShape')
```

**Note** that when you do have a custom shape, then turtle will automatically fill it in for you. So this won't be a circle, but a filled-in circle instead.

Comment: In your `drawCircle(radius,iterations, t)` function, you misuse the term `radius`.  When you call this with a `radius=1`, as in your example, you actually draw a circle with radius of roughly 11.5  -- what you call radius is actually the length of a side of a polygon.

Comment: You've failed to discuss or control where the *hot spot* is.  That is, the point from which the cursor draws and the point that covers the position the cursor moves to.  In the default circle cursor, it's the center of the circle.  On yours, its on the right edge.

Comment: Your example creates a cursor that has a *larger* radius than the default circle cursor that comes with Python, not *smaller* as your title and question desire.

Answer (score 3):

Working with the set of cursors that Python provides, including `'circle'`, you can adjust the size of the cursor using the `shapesize()` method (aka `turtlesize`):

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape('circle')
turtle.shapesize(0.5)  # make the cursor half the default size

turtle.forward(100)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Above, we resized it *relative* to it's *default* size.  If we want to size it to a *specific pixel size*, we start with the knowledge that the provided cursors are based on a 20px by 20px square, and adjust accordingly:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape('circle')
turtle.shapesize(15 / CURSOR_SIZE)  # make the cursor 15 pixels diameter
turtle.color('black', 'white')  # make it an open circle this time

turtle.forward(100)

screen.exitonclick()
```